# WebClient multi file Downloader error

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, .net-4.0

im using the following code to download 50+ files from my webserver

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

//downloads
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.site.com/file/loc.file"), @"c:\app\loc ");
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.site.com/file/loc.file"), @"c:\app\loc ");
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.site.com/file/loc.file"), @"c:\app\loc ");
 }

           void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        progressBar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
    }

    private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Game Update Finished!");
    }
```

im wanting to download 1 file at a time with a continuing progress bar iv got most of the coding done but when i hit the "Download" button i get the following error

> WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations.

what do i need to do?

Comment: Simply you are trying to write to the same file

Answer (score 2):

Feel the difference:

- It CAN download multiple files in parallel manner (by one stream per
  one file).
- But it CAN'T download one file using multiple streams.

Here is example (MainWindow contain one button 'Start' and five progress bars):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private WebClient _webClient;
    private ProgressBar[] _progressBars;
    private int _index = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _progressBars = new [] {progressBar1, progressBar2, progressBar3, progressBar4, progressBar5};
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 5;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _index);
        if (_index > _progressBars.Length)
            return;

        _webClient = new WebClient();
        _webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged;
        _webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += WebClient_DownloadFileCompleted;

        _webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"),
                                     System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName(),
                                     _index);
    }

    private void WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var index = (int) args.UserState;
        _progressBars[index-1].Value = args.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void WebClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        var index = (int)args.UserState;

        MessageBox.Show(args.Error == null
                            ? string.Format("Download #{0} completed!", index)
                            : string.Format("Download #{0} error!\n\n{1}", index, args.Error));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is ServicePointManager here @White. can u plzz tell me the usage of ServicePointManager or give full code. thanks

Comment: @Thomas I use its static property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx to limit connections count

Answer (score 1):

you are running multiple downloads in parallel with the same `WebClient` instance - the error tells you that this is NOT supported - you either:

- use multiple instances of `WebClient` (one per parallel download)
  OR
- download one file after the other

Relevant information:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700359.aspx

Answer (score 0):

WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations (multiple downloads) per instance, so you need to create a separate WebClient instance for each download. You can still perform each download asynchronously and use the same event handlers.

Comment: By use the same event handlers, I mean you can pool all the instance events into one method, but you'll have to modify your logic to aggregate the data because the event handler methods will be called from different instances.